# How do I restrict access to a single folder in a S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I want to restrict the access to a single folder in a S3 bucket, and I have written an IAM for it. However I am still not able to upload/sync the files to this folder. Here, `bucket` is the bucket name and `folder` is the folder I want to give access to.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowUserToSeeBucketListInTheConsole",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowRootAndHomeListingOfBucket",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        ""
                    ],
                    "s3:delimiter": [
                        "/"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowListingOfUserFolder",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:HeadObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "folder/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Please suggest where I am wrong.

Comment: Could you please Edit your question and add details of what you are attempting to do (eg show us the command you are using to upload/sync), and what error message appears. Also, are you using an IAM User or an IAM Role? If it is a Role, how are you using the role (eg is it being assigned to an EC2 instance, or is it being assumed)?

Answer (score 18):

This restrictive IAM policy grants only list and upload access to a particular prefix in a particular bucket. It also intends to allow multipart uploads.

References:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_Operations.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuAndPermissions.html

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ListBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": "my/prefix/is/this/*"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "UploadObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/my/prefix/is/this/*",
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that specifying the `s3:ListBucket` resource compactly as `"arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/my/prefix/is/this/*"` didn't work.

Comment: here works without /* - `"s3:prefix": "my/prefix/is/this"`

Comment: @Armando I think this is to restrict the List access only to that folder

Comment: Tested and this works prefect!

Answer (score 1):

Since you have requested to suggest, where you are wrong:
1> In AllowListingOfUserFolder, you have used the object as resource but you have used bucket level operations and "s3:prefix" will not work with object level APIs.

Please refer to the sample policies listed here:

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-policies-s3.html#iam-policy-ex1
- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket/

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ListObjectsInBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
            "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllObjectActions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*Object",
            "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"]
        }
    ]
}
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_rw-bucket.html

Answer (score -2):

I believe for the scenario you're describing AWS recommends Bucket Policies. AWS IAM should be used to secure AWS resources such as S3 itself, whereas Bucket policies can be used to secure S3 buckets and documents.

Check out this AWS blog post on the subject:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/iam-policies-and-bucket-policies-and-acls-oh-my-controlling-access-to-s3-resources/